# XQuery: How to retrieve the contents of an element once only despite multiple occurrences of a searchterm?

Tags: xml, xquery-3.0

I have an XML file with a bunch of `<entry>` elements in it (see below). I would like to extract most of the informations given in the `<entry>` container and put them in a (X)HTML document.

I'm able to perform a search and get the wanted element contents. If I search for the term `ἄγγελος` either in `entry/hyperlemma/orth` (path A) or in `cit/hyperlemma/orth` (path B), it is found once in entry01 in path A and twice in entry02 in path B.

The idea is that I print the content of each `entry` container where `ἄγγελος` was found, regardless of the amount of occurrences. As the term was found in entry02 twice, the entry gets (of course) printed twice, but I only need it once. Would that be possible to do with XQuery? And if so, how would I do that?

My XML:

```
<text>
    <entry xml:id="01">
        <hyperlemma>ἄγγελος</hyperlemma>
        <lemma>ἄγγελος</lemma>
        <variant>τῶν ἀγγέλων
            <hyperlemma>
                <orth>ἄγγελος</orth>
            </hyperlemma>
        </variant>
    </entry>
    <entry xml:id="02">
        <hyperlemma>
            <orth>ангелъ</orth>
        </hyperlemma>
        <lemma>
            <orth>ангелъ</orth>
        </lemma>
        <variant>
            <orth>анг꙯ла</orth>
            <hyperlemma>
                <orth>ангелъ</orth>
            </hyperlemma>
            <cit>
                <hyperlemma>
                    <orth>ἄγγελος</orth>
                </hyperlemma>
                <lemma>
                    <orth>ἄγγελον</orth>
                </lemma>
            </cit>
        </variant>
        <variant>
            <orth>анг꙯лъ</orth>
            <hyperlemma>
                <orth>ангелъ</orth>
            </hyperlemma>
            <cit>
                <hyperlemma>
                    <orth>ἄγγελος</orth>
                </hyperlemma>
                <lemma>
                    <orth>ἄγγελος</orth>
                </lemma>
            </cit>
        </variant>
    </entry>
</text>
```

My XQuery:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "xml";
declare variable $searchphrase := "ἄγγελος";
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Output of searchterm</h1>
        <p>You are looking for "<font color="red"><strong>{$searchphrase}</strong></font>"</p>
        {
        let $hyperlemmas := doc("sample_entry.xml")/(descendant::entry | descendant::cit)/hyperlemma/orth [contains(., $searchphrase)]
        return
        <p>{$searchphrase} was found {count($hyperlemmas)} times.</p>
        }
        {
        let $hyperlemmas := doc("sample_entry.xml")/(descendant::entry | descendant::cit)/hyperlemma/orth [contains(., $searchphrase)]
        for $hyperlemma in $hyperlemmas
        let $entry_id := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/@xml:id
        let $lemma := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/lemma/orth
        let $variant := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/variant/orth
        return
        <div>
            Entry {string($entry_id)}:<br/>
            Lemma: {$lemma} //
            {
            for $form in $variant
            return
            <i>{$form}</i>
            }
        </div>      
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using XQuery 3.0, a quick solution would be to group by entry IDs, which you're resolving anyway:

```
(: snip :)
for $hyperlemma in $hyperlemmas
let $entry_id := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/@xml:id
group by $entry_id
let $lemma := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/lemma/orth
let $variant := $hyperlemma/ancestor::entry/variant/orth
return
  (: snip :)
```

A more elegant solution (but pretty much resulting in a complete rewrite of the query) would be to loop over entry elements instead, and for each of those finding the first match and print this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions! In fact, `group by $entry_id` didn't work out, as I'm not sure what exactly happens when using the `group by` statement (and comprehensive documentation on that feature seems to be sparce). I had thought of looping over the `entry` elements myself before - to no avail. After sitting down and trying hard again yesterday, I finally came up with some code that does what I had in mind. I'll post it in another answer. I now have to test this with my much more complex XML data (stored in an eXist db), which involves using a Lucene index as well. Wish me luck!

Comment: With BaseX and the example data you posted it worked out fine.

Comment: I tested my code outside of eXist, using Oxygen Editor. Inserting `group by $entry_id` had to be done directly before the return statement, otherwise it would not run.

Comment: While the number of entries was correct, the output of entry02 was like `Lemma:  ангелъ  ангелъ  //  анг꙯ла   анг꙯лъ   анг꙯ла   анг꙯лъ `, so the output was somehow reduplicated. As I didn't find any satisfying documentation on how exactly the `group by` statement works, I tried figuring out looping over the `entry` elements - which in the end proved to be more successful. But thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out myself how I can just print certain elements inside of the `entry` tag when a given searchterm can be found at different postions. Here is the rewritten XQuery code that (for now) works for me and gives the intended results:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method   "xml";
declare variable $searchphrase := "ἄγγελος";
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Output of searchterm</h1>
        <p>You are looking for "<font color="red"><strong>{$searchphrase}</strong></font>"</p>
        {
        let $hyperlemmas := doc("sample_entry.xml")/(descendant::entry | descendant::cit)/hyperlemma/orth [contains(., $searchphrase)]
        let $ids := $hyperlemmas/ancestor::entry/@xml:id
        return
        <p>{$searchphrase} was found {count($hyperlemmas)} times. IDs: {data($ids)} </p>
        }
        {   
        let $entry_base := doc("sample_entry.xml")/text

        for $entry in $entry_base/entry
        let $id := $entry/@xml:id
        let $variant := $entry/variant/orth
        let $found_pos1 := $entry/hyperlemma/orth
        let $found_pos2 := $entry/descendant::cit/hyperlemma/orth
        where $found_pos1 = $searchphrase or $found_pos2 = $searchphrase
        return
        <div>ID {data($id)}:<br/>Lemma: {$entry/lemma/orth}<br/>
            {
            for $item in $variant
            return
            <div>Variant: {$item}
                {
                for $cit in $item/../cit/lemma
                where exists($cit)
                return
                <i>-> {$cit}</i>
                }
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```